# How to install Android applications without opening google market?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to promote some of my applications when user installs one of them. Is there a way to install them without sending the user to market?

For example to ask for permission when user install my app and then use it to receive access token and install applications with it.

Comment: no its not advisable.Users have installed your app and you should not do this. You can add a page in the app and let them download the from the play'

Answer (score 0):

Download apk file from the server to mobile, after that use following code to install application.

```
 Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(apk_filepath),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
 startActivity (promptInstall);
```

Comment: It will work only on devices with "Unknow sources" option set to yes, right?